# React - useEffect overriding props with multiple data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have problem with overriding mapped props in component with useEffect. This happend after update npm's and i dont know what to do right now.

Im using multiple API question in one component and the data is overriden by the last function in use Effect

I have no idea how to fix that, and why that happens? The wired think is, when i reverse functions, the last one will override all props

Case 1:

```
props.fetchAllClients();
props.fetchAllProducts();
```

Return : props.clientList = props.productList

Case 2:

```
props.fetchAllProducts();
props.fetchAllClients();
```

Return : props.productList = props.clientList

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        props.fetchAllProducts();
        props.fetchAllClients();
    };

    fetchData();
}, []);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    clientList: state.Client.list,
    productList: state.Product.list
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
    addRepair: repairActions.create,
    fetchAllClients: clientActions.fetchAll,
    fetchAllProducts: productActions.fetchAll
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(AddNewRepair);
```

EDIT:

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avF3Z.png)

[client reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaHrF.png)

[product reducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diDev.png)

[redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEG8A.png)

[client actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRB4y.png)

[product actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSGHO.png)

EDIT 2:

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import { Product } from "./product";
import { Repair } from "./repair";
import { Client } from "./client";

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    Product, Repair, Client,
})
```

reducers return :

```
const reducers: Reducer<CombinedState<{
    Product: {
        list: any[];
        groupedList: any[];
    };
    Repair: {
        list: any[];
    };
    Client: {
        list: any[];
    };
}>, AnyAction>
```

Comment: change your useEffect to be like: `useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchAllProducts();
        props.fetchAllClients();
  
}, []);` you don't need to wrap them in another function

Comment: I'm not sure how much this might help you, but I've started running my asyns fetch before the initial render.. the only way react doesn't complain and get all data I'm asking for.. I.e `fetchData().then(()=>{render(<App />) document...}

Comment: What do the redux devtools say? What actions are dispatched and what changes do they make to the state? Is there anything incorrect about what is happening? You tagged the question with redux thunk but I don't see any thunk code, your action and reducer code is missing.

Comment: @HMR Sorry for my missing informations, im begginer with react and redux, cany you help me righ now?

Comment: What does your `reducers/index.js` file look like? How are you combining the reducers? It sounds like they are writing to the same location in your store.

Comment: Please don't post pictures but code.

Comment: I think the problem is that for both client and product the action type is FETCH_ALL so both client and product reducer will set state on that action. Try to use FETCH_ALL_CLIENT and FETCH_ALL_PRODUCT instead.

Comment: @RossAllen in EDIT 2: code from index.js- reducers.
 -> jperl i can't post that much code :(
 -> HMR thank you i will try and give you answer.

Comment: @HMR after using your convetions there is no problem! Tell me how can i repay you...

Comment: @Darek No problem, I am happy to hear you got it working.